# Google PageSpeed Suggests I Specify A Cache Validator But I Don't Know How

Tags: google-maps-api-3, pdo

I ran Google's PageSpeed tool on this page: 
http://classifieds.your-adrenaline-fix.com/detail.php?fatherID=10&ListingID=7&TypeID=42

The results indicated that I should be specifying a cache validator - a Last-Modified or ETag header.

I have thoroughly read this:
https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching#LeverageProxyCaching

But I don't know what to do.

I do know that the problems I am experiencing (which are turning up via Google's PageSpeed tool) are stemming from the following code that displays a Google Map but this code is code that someone here helped me with. (even though I haven't YET learned anything about PDO and don't really understand the code)

I'm hoping someone could look over the code provided below to let me know that all that looks correct AND share with me how I could specify a cache validator to better the page per Google's Page Speed recommendations.

Any help will certainly be appreciated and I thank you all in advance.

Stuart K

Edit: Additionally, I have the following Code Within .htaccess: (with the Map code following)

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On 
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
# Favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>









$TypeID = isset($_GET['TypeID']) ? $_GET['TypeID'] : ''; 
            $ListingID = isset($_GET['ListingID']) ? $_GET['ListingID'] : ''; 
            $allowed_tables = array('tt_42', 'tt_43');//Array of allowed tables to sanatise query
            //Define table name
            $table ="tt_".$TypeID;
            //Connect to database
            $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $username, $password);
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            try {
                //Check if table name is in allowed list
                if (in_array($table, $allowed_tables)) {
                    //Prepare query
                $query = "SELECT *  FROM `$table` WHERE `ID` = ? AND `ExpireDate` > NOW()";
                }//end if
                // Prepare statement
                $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
                // Assign parameter
                $stmt->bindParam(1,$ListingID);
                //Execute query
                $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $stmt->execute();

                //New code
                $Address = $listing['Address'];
                $City = $listing['City'];
                $State = $listing['State/Province'];
                $Zip = $listing['Zip/Postal'];
                $Country = $listing['Country'];
                //End new code

                echo '<h2>Map of Surrounding Area With Navigational Aides</h2>';
                echo '<div class="CalloutBoxBlue">Hover over map and scroll, or use + and - in LH corner of map to zoom or expand viewing area. Alternatively, hold down mouse to manually move the map to a different geographical location, or drag the person icon to a specific location on the map for a street view.</div>';
                echo '<div id="GoogleMap">'; 
                //New code
                echo '<iframe scrolling="no" style="width:480px; height:300px; border:0px;" frameborder="0" src="googlemap.php?Address='.$Address.'&amp;City='.$City.'&amp;State='.$State.'&amp;Zip='.$Zip.'&amp;Country='.$Country.'"></iframe>'; 
                //End new code
                echo '</div>'; 
            }//End try


            catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo "I'm sorry I'm afraid you can't do that.". $e->getMessage() ;// Remove or modify after testing 
                file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt',date('[Y-m-d H:i:s]').", mapSelect.php, ". $e->getMessage()."\r\n", FILE_APPEND);  
             }


            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a cache validator using the `Cache-Control` header. Make sure you set it BEFORE you echo or print any content.

```
header('Cache-Control: <amount of seconds e.g. 3600 or 86400, "no-cache" for none>');
```

I also made some changes to your PDO code. I moved the if-statement to check if the table is allowed and added some code to actually retrieve the selected data.

```
header('Cache-Control: 900');   // 15 minutes

$TypeID = isset($_GET['TypeID']) ? $_GET['TypeID'] : ''; 
$ListingID = isset($_GET['ListingID']) ? $_GET['ListingID'] : ''; 
$allowed_tables = array('tt_42', 'tt_43');//Array of allowed tables to sanitise query
// Define table name
$table = "tt_" . $TypeID;
if (in_array($table, $allowed_tables)) {
    try {
        // Connect to database
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $username, $password);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        // Prepare query
        $query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE ID=? AND ExpireDate>NOW()";
        // Prepare statement
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
        // Assign parameter
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $ListingID);
        // Execute query
        $stmt->execute();

        // Fetch all results
        $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if (!empty($data)) {
            $listing = reset($data);

            // New code
            $Address = $listing['Address'];
            $City = $listing['City'];
            $State = $listing['State/Province'];
            $Zip = $listing['Zip/Postal'];
            $Country = $listing['Country'];
            // End new code

            echo '<h2>Map of Surrounding Area With Navigational Aides</h2>';
            echo '<div class="CalloutBoxBlue">Hover over map and scroll, or use + and - in LH corner of map to zoom or expand viewing area. Alternatively, hold down mouse to manually move the map to a different geographical location, or drag the person icon to a specific location on the map for a street view.</div>';
            echo '<div id="GoogleMap">'; 
            // New code
            echo '<iframe scrolling="no" style="width: 480px; height: 300px; border: 0px;" frameborder="0" src="googlemap.php?Address=' . $Address . '&amp;City=' . $City . '&amp;State=' . $State . '&amp;Zip=' . $Zip . '&amp;Country=' . $Country . '"></iframe>'; 
            // End new code
            echo '</div>';
        } else {
            // Show "no addresses found" message
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "I'm sorry I'm afraid you can't do that." . $e->getMessage();  // Remove or modify after testing 
        file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', date('[Y-m-d H:i:s]') . ", mapSelect.php, " . $e->getMessage(). "\r\n", FILE_APPEND);  
    }
}
```